# How do I access the Facebook Business SDK for NodeJS package on my Wix site?

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, velo

I am trying to make two API call types [`GET` & `POST`] from a Wix website to our Facebook Marketing APP.

- `GET` to request some analytics from FB APP and pull into a Wix dataset
- `POST` to send ad/ ad set/ campaign build requests to FB APP *** We have a page that contains a FB ad builder *prototype* we put together. All information is gathered into a Wix dataset upon 'submit button'

*The Node package in place for this need is an approved Wix package and is downloaded directly through Corvid - Facebook Business SDK for NodeJS package - (https://www.npmjs.com/package/facebook-nodejs-business-sdk)

I just can't seem to figure out how to translate the FB Developers step by step into the Wix Corvid framework. I have a good understanding of the process that is carried out in this API call and feel like I have all the pieces needed to do this... but I admittedly have limited knowledge of the actual code required to expose my wix API and communicate with our FB APP in a Corvid environment. Particularly making the calls between backend, user & node package.

- We have an active FB Marketing app and have successfully executed `post` and `get` requests directly in the APP
- We have all necessary permissions on our APP to execute the API calls
- FB Log in SDK is implemented into the site and works - but needs to be expanded on.

Example `post` workflow needed:

-User goes to FB ad builder prototype on Wix page

-User logs into Facebook on page

-Confirms our FB APPS requested permissions needed to make the API request

-Selects what FB business page to give permissions to [if applicable]

-User completes prototype ad builder form [text,options,images{up to 5,}, video {1 max}]

-User clicks submit

-API `post` is triggered and the ad is published on their Facebook business page

*
Wix `Fetch` and Wix `HTTP Functions` API references:

https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-fetch

https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-http-functions

*
Only direct Wix Corvid 3p API connection examples I have found are for Mailchimp, Stripe and a Weather App . None of them *seem* to fit the format needed and none are as intricate.  They also don't dive very deep in details...

*
A few extra Wix references and examples of API connections:

https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-accessing-third-party-services-with-the-fetch-api

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzAHCaflzY8

https://codingthesmartway.com/how-to-create-a-web-app-with-external-api-access-using-wix-code/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gF7ST661Ozc

https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-exposing-a-site-api-with-http-functions

*

Facebook Developers Marketing App API reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis

*

This may all be here in front of me but any and all suggestions to help bridge my understanding of this API connection will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!